# Justify the fact that antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln |x|$ not $\ln x$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Justify the fact that antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\ln |x|$ not $\ln x$

Does the derivatives domain $have$ to be the $same$ as the original functions?

$\frac{1}{x} \neq 0$, but $\ln x >0$. Their domains don't agree, but how can this prove that the derivative is $not$ $\frac{1}{x}.$

---

I $can$ prove that derivative of $\ln |x|$ is in fact $\frac{1}{x}$, but why does simple $\ln x$ not work?

Comment: $\ln x > 0$ is false, though it doesn't change your question.

Comment: The "fact" is incorrect; you're ignoring the constant of integration. Moreover, since $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, a disconnected domain, there can be different constants of integration for $x>0$ and $x<0$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 that's a good point, I better add that to my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An antiderivative of a function $f(x)$ is a function $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for every point in the domain of $f$. So yes, the domain of the antiderivative should be the same.

The domain of $\ln x$ is $x>0$ whereas the domain of $1/x$ is all of $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0$, which is strictly larger (it includes the negative axis $x<0$). Therefore $\ln x$ cannot be the antiderivative on the entire domain $\mathbb{R}\setminus 0$; we must find a way to extend the function to the larger domain.

The part of $1/x$ defined on the negative real axis has an antiderivative too, it is $\ln(-x),$ since the domain of $\ln(-x)$ is $x<0$ and $\frac{d(\ln(-x))}{dx}=\frac{1}{-x}\cdot\frac{d(-x)}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}$.

We can capture both functions on the larger domain with the absolute value $\ln|x|$, which is just $\ln x$ on the positive axis, $\ln(-x)$ on the negative axis.

Note that while $\ln|x|$ is *an* antiderivative of $1/x$, it's not the most general one, nor even is $\ln|x|+C$ for any constant $C$. Because of the disconnected domain, you may choose different constants, so the most general antiderivative defined on the whole domain of $1/x$ is
$$
\begin{cases}
\ln x + C_1, & \text{if }x\ > 0 \\
\ln(-x) + C_2, & \text{if } x < 0 \\
\end{cases}
$$
and $C_1$ need not equal $C_2$. Thanks to MathematicsStudent1122 for reminding me of this fact.

Comment: Interesting, I see. However, when we add a constant, we don't really change the domain, its just vertical shift.

Comment: That's right. The issue about the constants is not directly relevant to the question of whether the antiderivative should have the same domain as the function. However the decision to include the entire disconnected domain does bring up this possibility of a function shifted by different amounts at different parts of its domain. So it's not just a shift of $\ln x$

Comment: You can also write it as $\ln\lvert x\rvert+C_1+C_2\frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}$.